# Как деплоить glassfish в intellij idea?

Tags: java, java-ee, glassfish

Установил GlassFish, создал новый проект>сервлет 
со след. содержанием:

```
@WebServlet("/book")
public class FindBooks extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Запускаю `GlassFish`, перехожу в  браузер, пишу localhost:8080/book в ожидание увидеть сервлет, но выдает 404, обьясните как все сделать.

Comment: `localhost:8080/тут-должно-быть-имя-вашего-веб-приложения/book`

Comment: А нужно ли что то писать в web.xml? 
В Deployment у меня есть web:war exploded. Это и есть имя приложения?

Comment: просто `web`без `war`. в `web.xml` вроде ничего не надо. `@WebServlet("/book")` заменяет описание сервлета в xml-е

Comment: У меня именно web:war exploded. В том то и дело, что аннотация должна заменить описание в xml, но у меня он не заполняется..
Я что то намудрил, надеюсь в лучшую сторону, что теперь он отдает просто пустую страницу но не 404 как было раньше.
Можете скинуть сорцы с GlassFish с сервлетом который у меня или любой другой который выводит какое-нибудь сообщение, а я посмотрю что у меня не так и исправлю, буду очень рад.

Comment: Там что у вас двоеточие между web и war? Откуда оно там взялось?

Comment: Не знаю, только вчера скачал GlassFish, может проблема в IDE.
И запускается проект по такому пути:
http://localhost:8080/untitled9_war_exploded

Comment: В Eclipse у меня все получилось.